# How to create a struct of structs of known maximum size

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, arm, cmsis

**Edit**: I am now aware of the confusion I made between array and pointer. I appreciate the remarks but won't make the question more accurate, as it would lose part of the reason I wrote it.

I am trying to initialize a struct made of structs each containing an array. More clearly, I have this matrix structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t numRows;     /**< number of rows of the matrix.     */
    uint16_t numCols;     /**< number of columns of the matrix.  */
    float32_t *pData;     /**< points to the data of the matrix. */
} arm_matrix_instance_f32;
```

and I need to put a number of these matrix objects together into a bigger struct

```
typedef struct
{
    arm_matrix_instance_f32 A;
    arm_matrix_instance_f32 B;
    arm_matrix_instance_f32 C;
} dataset;
```

For reference, this matrix definition and the initialisation function used later, come from the `arm_math` library in [CMSIS](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS).

I am having difficulties understanding how I should create a `dataset` variable. Following the answers and discussion in this [question page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263723/struct-with-array-of-structs-of-unknown-size), I understand I cannot magically expect C to know how much memory to allocate with a declaration such as `dataset d`.

Following only the solution to the linked question, I came up with a function to initialise enough space for a `dataset`, and with a function to create a variable of type `dataset`. I have now something like this:

```
dataset* create_dataset( void ) {

    uint8_t n_matrices = 3;
    uint8_t n_elements = 9;
    dataset* d= malloc( n_matrices * (sizeof(float32_t)*n_elements + sizeof(uint16_t)*2));
    memset(d, 0, sizeof(*d));

    const float32_t zeros33_f32[9] =
    {
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    };
    const float32_t zeros31_f32[3] =
    {
        0.0,
        0.0,
        0.0,
    };
    const float32_t zeros13_f32[3] =
    {
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    };

    arm_mat_init_f32( &(d->A), 3, 3, (float32_t *)zeros33_f32);
    arm_mat_init_f32( &(d->B), 3, 1, (float32_t *)zeros31_f32);
    arm_mat_init_f32( &(d->C), 1, 3, (float32_t *)zeros13_f32);

    return d;
}
```

Basically I start from the assumption that both the number of matrices and the maximum number of elements they contain are known, and consequently reserve enough memory.

I have the following questions:

1. Is if the overall approach correct for such nested structs?
2. Is the allocation of space for the `dataset` struct correct?
3. Am I actually ensuring that all `arm_matrix_instance_f32` elements contained in the `dataset` struct I create have enough space for all their elements?
4. I declared the struct as containing `A, B, C`. What happens if I initialise them in another order? For example, how would the struct know how much space to leave between `A` and `C` if `B` is still not declared?

Comment: `memset(d, 0, sizeof(*d));` isn't going to zero your data. Use `calloc` for this

Comment: Looking at `arm_mat_init_f32` function definition here: https://www.cs.indiana.edu/~bhimebau/CMSIS/Documentation/DSP/html/group___matrix_init.html I wonder where is the function like `arm_mat_release_f32`? If such function doesn't exist, I can guess that `arm_mat_init_f32` just populates the `arm_matrix_instance_f32` fields and doesn't make any allocations. In this case your code is wrong, because after `create_dataset` function exits, all `pData` pointers become invalid.

Comment: However, you need to know the API you are using, give some more information to get the answer.

Comment: There is no array in your `struct`. A pointer **is not** an array. And this seems to be some bare-metal MCU system. It's generally a very bad idea to use `malloc` & co on such systems.

Comment: And that's an XY problem anyway. You use a very wrong approach.

Comment: @AlexF from what I understood looking at the functions, the init function simply populates the fields, as you guessed. I don't understand though why my method would be incorrect, because the output I am passing is a pointer to the `dataset` structure, in which the pointers to `arm_matrix_instance_f32` structs should not get lost. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Olaf, thank you. Could you elaborate on the 'XY problem'? What do you mean by that? If you could point me to the right approach I'll be very glad!

Comment: @raggot: For the correct approach I had to know project details, the architecture, platform, etc. That's far beyond what this site is for. I'd advise to step back and start with something simpler to leran the language properly and get some practice first. Don't try to run before you can walk. If that's an embedded project as I assume, this is even more vital: they have much less tolerance to problematic/faulty code.

Comment: @raggot: all `pData` pointers become invalid when `create_dataset` returns, since they point to local arrays.

Comment: @AlexF. I had missed that...! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a variable of type `dataset` (or any `struct` for that matter):

```
dataset d;
```

That's it. Nothing more to it.

To allocate an object of type `dataset` (or any `struct` for that matter) on the heap:

```
dataset* dp = malloc(sizeof(dataset));
```

That's it. Nothing more to it.

Now to *initialise* such an object properly is a different issue. But in order to initialize something, you need to create that something first. It is best to keep these two processes, creation and initialisation, mentally separated.

So you have an uninitialised `struct` on your hands. How to initialise it? Field by field.

Each field is a matrix, which may require its own complex initialisation, so it is beneficial to write a dedicated matrix initialisation function. Let's use one first, and write it later. Let's assume you have to allocate your dataset on the heap.

```
dataset* allocate_dataset() {
       dataset* dp = malloc(sizeof(dataset));
       if (dp == NULL) { /* report out-of-memory error */ }
       init_matrix(&dp->A, 3, 3);
       init_matrix(&dp->B, 3, 1);
       init_matrix(&dp->C, 1, 3);
       return dp;
}
```

Whatever is allocated on the heap must eventually be freed, so we write a symmetrical deallocation function:

```
void free_dataset(dataset* dp) {
       destroy_matrix(&dp->A);
       destroy_matrix(&dp->B);
       destroy_matrix(&dp->C);
       free(dp);
}
```

On to matrix initialisation. There is a library function that does it, but it needs a  pointer to its data array, which should be allocated somewhere. I assume it lives on the heap.

```
void init_matrix(arm_mat_init_f32* mp, int rows, int cols) {
    float32_t* data = malloc(sizeof(float32_t * rows * cols);
    if (data == NULL) { /* report out-of-memory error */ }
    arm_mat_init_f32(mp, rows, cols, data);   
}
```

Destroying a matrix is almost trivial:

```
void destroy_matrix(arm_mat_init_f32* mp) {
    free (mp->pData);
}
```

Again, this assumes you need to allocate your matrix data on the heap. This is not necessarily the case. Perhaps you are on an embedded device with limited memory. Now let's assume the opposite: no heap. You don't need to allocate your dataset, bit you still need to initialise it:

```
void init_dataset (dataset* dp);
```

And now init_matrix does nothing but calls `arm_mat_init_f32`, so we can just use the latter directly:

```
void init_dataset (dataset* dp) {
    arm_mat_init_f32(&dp->A, 3, 3, (float32_t[]){0,0,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0});
    arm_mat_init_f32(&dp->B, 3, 1, (float32_t[]){0,0,0});
    arm_mat_init_f32(&dp->C, 1, 3, (float32_t[]){0,0,0});
}
```

Destruction is not needed, but you may want to still keep destruction functions that do nothing, just in case, and call them wherever appropriate.

```
void destroy_dataset(dataset* dp) { 
    destroy_matrix(&dp->A);
    destroy_matrix(&dp->B);
    destroy_matrix(&dp->C);
}

void destroy_matrix(arm_mat_init_f32* mp) { 
  (void)mp; // suppress compiler warning
}
```

Why? Because you don't want to redo *all* of your code once you change your mind (or switch to a different device) and decide to allocate matrices on the heap. You just modify your `init` and `destroy` functions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take more granular approach to this and start from allocating space for each `arm_matrix_instance_f32` separately. Consider creating a factory function for those instances. It will produce more readable code and will allow you to simply replace `arm_matrix_instance_f32` in your `dataset` with other instances.

On the other hand if you always know the number of matrices and the maximum number of elements they contain you can use compound literals to generate your dataset:

```
 dataset create()
 {
     return (dataset) {
         .A = {
             3, 3, (float32_t [])  {
                 1.0, 2.0, 3.0,
                 4.0, 5.0, 6.0,
                 7.0, 8.0, 9.0,
             }
         },
         .B = {
             3, 3, (float32_t [])  {
                 2.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
             }
         },
         .C = {
             3, 3, (float32_t [])  {
                 2.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
             }
         },

     };
 }
```

This will free you from heap allocation/deallocation.

Comment: I like this approach. A bit verbose (I actually have 25 matrices currently, not 3) but clear and seems to take care of all memory management problems in one go. I will try it in a bit and get back to you.

Comment: @raggot "I actually have 25 matrices currently" It is probably not a very good idea to have a struct of 25 identically typed elements. An array might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Beware, pointers and arrays are different animals!

Here, the `arm_matrix_instance_f32` contains no array but a pointer. And `dataset` contains 3 of them. Full stop.

That means that this line is plain wrong:

```
dataset* d= malloc( n_matrices * (sizeof(float32_t)*n_elements + sizeof(uint16_t)*2));
```

You should instead separately allocate the struct and the arrays:

```
dataset* create_dataset( void ) {

    dataset* d = malloc(sizeof(*d));                  // allocate memory for the structs
    if (d == NULL) return NULL;                       // could not allocate
    // allocate memory for the arrays (9 + 3 + 3)
    float32_t *array = malloc(15 +  * sizeof(*array));
    if (array == NULL) {
        free(d);                                      // free d if array not allocated
        return NULL;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<15; i++) array[i] = 0.;           // zeroes the arrays

    arm_mat_init_f32( &(d->A), 3, 3, array);          // pass 9 first elements to A
    arm_mat_init_f32( &(d->B), 3, 1, array + 9);      // pass following 3 to B
    arm_mat_init_f32( &(d->C), 1, 3, array + 12);     // pass last 3 to C

    return d;
}
```

As you have allocated everything with `malloc` you will have to free it later:

```
void destroy_dataset(dataset *d) {
    free(d->A.pData);      // free the array (A got the beginning of the allocated array)
    free(d);               // and the struct
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This gives me the idea of where I have to put my hands. Any idea why the answer was downvoted? Perhaps there can be more elegant ways to run the initialization functions instead of hard-coding the size?

Comment: @raggot: For the downvote, I do not know, but malloc on an embedded device where memory is limited should be used very cautiously, what my initial code did not.